# Symbols using Jquery .get() are not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I use `$.get()` to reload my page every so often, I do this because there are timers that count down showing when something is due and this works better than an actual page refresh and .load() would not work, however the symbols on the page **™ µ** do not load there is only a tiny square box instead. Is there some way to get them to load properly? The symbols are from copy righted names of products. Theses names are pulled from a programs database and they show up fine until the $.get() is loaded.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var loc = window.location;
    var pathName = ".."+loc.pathname.substring(43, loc.pathname.lastIndexOf('.') + 4);

    $.get(pathName, function(data) {
        $('#pagebody').html(data);
```

There is the code that i'm using the `$.get()` in

Comment: I need to know what I've done wrong here, why has this been put on hold?

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(data)` to verify correct data is received?

Comment: Is your page in UTF-8 charset ?

Comment: No its set to ANSI if I put it in anything else the software program doesn't read it any longer.

Comment: I see I can use UTF-8 charset, but no it is set in ANSI. Like I said it reads the symbols fine until the `$.get()` is loaded.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour Where would I put the console.log(data), I'm new to JavaScript and Jquery? I tried replacing the html with console.log but that didn't work.

Comment: Inside your `get`'s callback. You could place it before `$('#pagebody').html(data);`.

Comment: http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners. The basic problem seems to be a mismatch of character encoding. Your page is set to one encoding and the AJAX request returns data in another encoding.

Comment: @Juhana so how do I fix that?

Comment: Make sure both encodings are the same. It's pretty hard to say anything else without knowing where the data is coming from.

Comment: @Juhana well that data is being loaded from the same page i'm using it refresh the content, not loading new data.

Comment: oddly enough when you use the console.log the data that is retrevied is without the symbols which I find odd, so something happens to it when it is loaded from `$.get()`

Comment: make sure that if your script is an external file, then that file must match the encoding of the html file that includes it..

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli its the same file. So the script file is encoded with ANSI then a piece of software takes that script loads the information from the program and makes an out file which is the same as the script just loaded with info from the software. So everything works fine until I use `$.get();` to load the same out file something happens using `$.get();` that won't let me load to special characters that load when the page loads but not when the .get reloads it.

Comment: Also normal keyboard symbol work just not the  ™ or µ

Comment: I was hoping there was some sort of script to make the page understand what those were and display them.

Comment: what's wrong with using `load()`?

Comment: it wont load the data from the software because the data is load inside of a javascript like this `<script type="text/javascript">[ItemsHTML]</script>` I don't quite understand how that calls the data, but it does so trying to use .load with that makes it so the data that is loaded is without that script leaving it blank, .get for some reason works.